# HTML5 Video Dimensions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-video

I'm trying to get the dimensions of a video of which I'm overlaying onto a page with JavaScript, however it is returning the dimensions of the poster image instead of the actual video as it seems it's being calculated before the video is loaded.

Comment: Did you give up? There are good clues as answers here!

Answer (score 128, accepted):

```
<video id="foo" src="foo.mp4"></video>

var vid = document.getElementById("foo");
vid.videoHeight; // returns the intrinsic height of the video
vid.videoWidth; // returns the intrinsic width of the video
```

Spec: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/embedded-content.html#the-video-element

Comment: Is this possible with the ogg format as I don't think the video will include such metadata?

Comment: @Elliot I tested in Chrome on this demo: http://people.opera.com/howcome/2007/video/controls.html and it works...

Comment: It seems the link is broken again

Comment: Sorry the link is not broken in fact

Comment: always zero when playing a local file with `URL.createObjectURL( file )`

Answer (score 175):

It should be noted that the currently accepted solution above by Sime Vidas doesn't actually work in modern browsers since the videoWidth and videoHeight properties aren't set until after the "loadedmetadata" event has fired.

If you happen to query for those properties far enough after the VIDEO element is rendered it may sometimes work, but in most cases this will return values of 0 for both properties.

To guarantee that you're getting the correct property values you need to do something along the lines of:

```
var v = document.getElementById("myVideo");
v.addEventListener( "loadedmetadata", function (e) {
    var width = this.videoWidth,
        height = this.videoHeight;
}, false );
```

NOTE: I didn't bother accounting for pre-9 versions of Internet Explorer which use attachEvent instead of addEventListener since pre-9 versions of that browser don't support HTML5 video, anyway.

Comment: I am getting values of 100 for both width and height, and video doesn't have 100px. Not sure why...

Comment: This doesn't work on Chrome for Android 49 unfortunately; only when the video has started playing the info becomes available. Any further insight on this? PS1: I only tried this with URLs to local files selected using an file selector input element. PS2 : it does work on iOS Safari.

Comment: I created this issue at the chromium bug tracker : https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=598218

Comment: This won't work 100% of the times. On rare occasions videoWidth and videoHeight will be zero when `loadedmetadata` fires. I just saw it on Chromium 69. Listening for `loadeddata` is a safer bet.

Answer (score 40):

## Ready-to-use function

Here's a ready to use function which returns the dimensions of a video asynchrously, **without changing anything in the document**.

```js
// ---- Definitions ----- //

/**
 Returns the dimensions of a video asynchrounsly.
 @param {String} url Url of the video to get dimensions from.
 @return {Promise<{width: number, height: number}>} Promise which returns the dimensions of the video in 'width' and 'height' properties.
 */
function getVideoDimensionsOf(url){
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        // create the video element
        const video = document.createElement('video');

        // place a listener on it
        video.addEventListener( "loadedmetadata", function () {
            // retrieve dimensions
            const height = this.videoHeight;
            const width = this.videoWidth;

            // send back result
            resolve({height, width});
        }, false);

        // start download meta-datas
        video.src = url;
    });
}


// ---- Use ---- //
getVideoDimensionsOf("https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4")
   .then(console.log);
```

Here's the video used for the snippet if you wish to see it : [Big Buck Bunny](https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4)

Comment: Great use of a promise to deliver video tag data asynchronously, just what I was looking for thanks

Comment: Great code, and has decent browser support: As of Chrome 32, Opera 19, Firefox 29, Safari 8 & Microsoft Edge, promises are enabled by default.

Comment: Run this code snippet gives `Undefined`

Answer (score 15):

Listen for the `loadedmetadata` event which is dispatched when the user agent has just determined the duration and dimensions of the media resource

#### Section 4.7.10.16 Event summary

https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/semantics-embedded-content.html#eventdef-media-loadedmetadata

```
videoTagRef.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function(e){
    console.log(videoTagRef.videoWidth, videoTagRef.videoHeight);
});
```

Comment: Correct link : https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#event-media-loadedmetadata

Comment: @Visionscaper Fixed, thanks. Feel free to make small edits other's answers when they don't change the original intention.

Answer (score 3):

This is how it can be done in Vue:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <video src="video.mp4" @loadedmetadata="getVideoDimensions"></video>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    methods: {
        getVideoDimensions (e) {
            console.log(e.target.videoHeight)
            console.log(e.target.videoWidth)
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

**This should also be noted** 
that in some cases such as **HLS streams**
the "onmetadataloaded" does not work either.
 in those cases, this solution works perfect.

```
var video = document.getElementById("video")
video.onplaying = function () {
    var width = video.videoWidth
    var height = video.videoHeight
    console.log("video dimens loaded w="+width+" h="+height)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In Vuejs I use following code in mounted tag.

```
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#id_homepage',
    mounted: function () {
        var v = document.getElementById("id_video");
        var width = v.offsetWidth;
        v.height = Math.floor(width*(9/16)); // dynamically setting video height to maintain aspect ratio
    },
});
```