# getting video dimensions before upload, client-side

Tags: javascript, jquery, apache-flex, html, video

I have an upload form for an video. The user clicks browse and selects a file. How can I get the video dimensions the moment the user selects the file (before the file is even uploaded to the server). It obviously has to be something client-side with maybe javascript/jquery or flash/flex (prefer js//jquery though), but can either of them do this?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, the short answer is you can't - You'd need access to scan the file contents using javascript which isn't allowed. Worse than that, even if you could read the file somehow, you'd need to implement a whole host of codecs in JS just to read the header information.

Mark this one as not possible

Comment: Maybe I don't have to read the file itself, but the metadata. This sort of information should be stored there, or maybe someone knows another trick for doing this

Comment: I understand what you're thinking but in most OSes, there is no metadata - All you have is a single file with no additional information. Windows / other OSes can parse simple data from known file types which they expose through property dialogs/etc. but fort video, the OS usually needs the codec installed and I've never heard of any way to do that from within JS - In addition, it would be a HUGE security issue - any website could just read metadata about any file on your hard disk...

Answer (score 3):

In theory you should be able to use the FileReader API - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/FileReader

Once the file has been read, you can parse out the headers. As far as I know, nobody has ever done this in javascript.

Comment: +1 Interesting solution but you'd still need to implement all the possible codecs in JS to actually understand the container/stream headers - which sounds like a bit of a nightmare. +1 for finding a possible solution but I don't think it's viable...

Answer (score 1):

This is a very old question but now it's possible to know video dimensions on client side before upload.

Refer to this question: [HTML5 Video Dimensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4129102/html5-video-dimensions)

Example code:

```
var v = document.getElementById("myVideo");
v.addEventListener( "loadedmetadata", function (e) {
    var width = this.videoWidth,
        height = this.videoHeight;
}, false );
```

Comment: How do you load a video element with a local file in this case?

Comment: @Basic you could load the local video file using a <video> element and then proceed. In my case, after user selects the <input> file, i create file URI and create a <video> element.

Answer (score 0):

If dimensions is resolution: no

If dimensions is file-size: (now) yes:

[Using jQuery, Restricting File Size Before Uploading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307679/using-jquery-restricting-file-size-before-uploading/9106313#9106313)