# getting minutes of video before uploading to amazon bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, video-processing

I want to upload video to Amazon bucket , but before that I want to know lenght of video in minutes, 
is it posssible using php,jquery,javascript ???

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, getting specific information like duration requires you to be able to implement a whole host of different codecs in javascript just to read the appropriate headers and get this information.

While you can read the file and scan its contents with the FileReader API, it's a whole other ball game parsing this content and getting the information you require.

This is discussed more on [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4932723/getting-video-dimensions-before-upload-client-side) with similar requirements.