# Detect aspect ratio - HTML5 video

Tags: html, video, html5-video, aspect-ratio

Is it possible to detect the aspect ratio of an HTML5 video element?

I know the video will just shrink to fit in the `<video>` element's dimensions, but I want to detect the aspect ratio of the source video.

That way you could remove any black bars.

Sorry I don't see this answered anywhere else.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML5 Video Dimensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4129102/html5-video-dimensions)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Pasting from another StackOverflow answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/4129189/1353189

```
<video id="foo" src="foo.mp4"></video>

var vid = document.getElementById("foo");
vid.videoHeight; // returns the intrinsic height of the video
vid.videoWidth; // returns the intrinsic width of the video
```

Source (HTML5 spec): http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/video.html#video

You can then calculate the aspect ratio by dividing the width by the height.