# videojs: how to get source video resolution or aspect?

Tags: video.js

Do you know or have ideas how I can get source video resolution or aspect in videojs?

I have looked vjs.Player, but it just return windows size, not original video size.

Thanks,
Andrey

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14904623/detect-aspect-ratio-html5-video

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML5 Video Dimensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4129102/html5-video-dimensions)

Answer (score 1):

```
<video id="player" onplaying="onplaying()"></video>
<script>
var player = videojs('player', {
  autoplay: true,
  controls: false,
  poster: ''
});
player.src("http://your.video.src");

function onplaying(){
  console.log(player.videoHeight());
  console.log(player.videoWidth());
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

So for

```
  <video id="video0"
```

we have

```
        var vid2 = document.getElementById('video0_flash_api');
        w = vid2.vjs_getProperty("videoWidth");
        h = vid2.vjs_getProperty("videoHeight");
```