# HTML5 Video Source Properties

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

So I have this structure:

```
<div style="width: 700px; height: 400px;">
   <video style="width: 100%; height: 100%">
</div>
```

I need to know, after the video is loaded, how can i find out the original dimensions of the video, or at least the aspect ratio, the video duration, etc.

Is this possible? how?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4129102/html5-video-dimensions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go - I guess the property names speak for themselves:

```
var video = document.getElementById('video');
console.log(video.duration);
console.log(video.videoHeight);
console.log(video.videoWidth);
```

The *aspect ratio* can be calculated by the width and height.

From [w3.org: 4.8.6 The video element](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-author-view/video.html#video):

> video.videoWidth / video.videoHeight: These attributes return the *intrinsic dimensions* of the video, or zero if the dimensions are not known.

Answer (score 0):

In the video tag just add the attribute controls to show the deails

Example

```
<div style="width: 700px; height: 400px;">
    <video style="width: 100%; height: 100%" controls>
        <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
    </video>
</div>
```

Hope this helps