# get height and width of hidden video

Tags: javascript, html, video, canvas

I have tried:

```
video.height // never worked
video.offsetHeight // worked when video was visible, now returning 0
```

for the purpose of showing only a processed video, I keep the video element hidden, and if I am drawing it on the screen in certain intervals, the below code works(even witht eh video hidden),

```
var video = document.getElementById('someVid');
var canvas = document.getElementById('someCanvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0, canvas.height, canvas.width);
```

I need the height and width for some processing, before drawing, so the new draw line would be:

```
ctx.drawImage(video, x, y, w, h, 0, 0, canvas.height, canvas.width);
```

for calculation of that `x,y,w,h` I need hidden video's height, width.

p.s: no need IE support, only firefox and chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, found the solution,

```
var height = video.videoHeight;
var width =  video.videoWidth;
```

returns intrinsic values...

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4129102/html5-video-dimensions)