# Javascript get video width/height before upload

Tags: javascript, video, mp4, jquery-file-upload, asyncfileupload

I'm looking for solution where I can prevent upload of some sort of videos, for that I need a way to grab video width/height via JS before file is being uploaded at all. Do we have such a mechanism or server side is the only way to go?

Comment: Are you using `file-reader` ?

Comment: I use plupload at the moment.

Comment: Have a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4129102/html5-video-dimensions

Comment: @MathijsVandenWorm, For that, you need video element to be there in DOM

Comment: yeah I sow that one, idea is to check is video low quality before upload, before I send files to server.

Comment: @vaske, I would preview video element using some absolute positioned hidden container and I could read the width and height using link provided above!

Comment: @RayonDabre sounds interesting will try that approach.