# Canvas width and height sometimes fails to resize

Tags: javascript, canvas, breakpoints

When video size changes I want to resize the canvas that overlays it, but sometimes the canvas fails to resize.

I have looked at other questions but they have a different issue.

```
function resizeCanvas(event) {
  if(!canvas){
    return;
  }
  var videoElement = event.target; // if breakpoint here, and step thru, it works.
  canvas.width = videoElement.offsetWidth; // sometimes fails to set
  canvas.height = videoElement.offsetHeight; // sometimes fails to set
} // if breakpoint here, it doesn't work.
```

Sometimes canvas.width and height are set to those of the video element, but sometimes they are not. I've confirmed that the function is called successfully with a breakpoint. But when I place the breakpoint at the end of the function, I find that the canvas.width and videoElement.offsetWidth are different! So canvas.width was not set.
However, if I place the breakpoint at the beginning of the function and step thru, then the width and height are always set. Very strange.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: This SO answer may be useful: [HTML5 Video Dimensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4129102/html5-video-dimensions#4129189)

Comment: Thanks; I learned what is the difference between offsetWidth and videoWidth. This may be useful in the future.